# Validation is done well when I modify an existing object, it does not work in the creation

Tags: php, validation, symfony

I worry a validation does not work when I create a new object "resa" but works if I change an existing object.

I can not find where it comes !?

My entity:

```php
<?php

namespace Damias\ResaBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Damias\ResaBundle\Validator\Constraints as ResaAssert;

/**
 * Reservation
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Damias\ResaBundle\Entity\ReservationRepository")
 * @ResaAssert\ResaUnique
 */
class Reservation
{
...
```

My constraint:

```php
<?php

namespace Damias\ResaBundle\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

/**
 * @Annotation
 */
class ResaUnique extends Constraint
{
    public $message = 'Réservation en conflit (chambre déjà occupée dans cette période)';

    public function getTargets()
    {
        return self::CLASS_CONSTRAINT;
    }

    public function validatedBy()
    {
        return 'damiasresa_resaunique';
    }
}
```

My validator:

```php
<?php

namespace Damias\ResaBundle\Validator\Constraints;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;

class ResaUniqueValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    private $requestStack;
    private $em;

    public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack, EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->requestStack=$requestStack;
        $this->em=$em;
    }

    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        $dateArrivee=clone $value->getDateArrivee();
        $dateArrivee->modify('+1 day');
        $dateDepart=clone $value->getDateDepart();
        $dateDepart->modify('-1 day');
        $ressources=$value->getRessources()->getValues();
        $id_ressources=array();
        foreach ($ressources as $ressource)
        {
            $id_ressources[]=$ressource->getId();
        }
        $autre_resa=$this   ->em
                            ->getRepository('DamiasResaBundle:Reservation')
                            ->autreResa($id_ressources, $dateArrivee, $dateDepart);

        if (count($autre_resa)>1)
        {
                $this->context  ->buildViolation($constraint->message)
                                ->atPath('Ressources')
                                ->addViolation();
        }
    }
}
```

My editing action that works:

```php
    public function reservationAction($id)
    {
        // SESSION
        $session = $this->get('session');

        $em = $this ->getDoctrine()
                    ->getManager();
        $resa = $em ->getRepository('DamiasResaBundle:Reservation')->find($id);

        $form_reservation = $this   ->createForm(new ReservationType, $resa);

        $request = $this->get('request');
        if($request->getMethod()=='POST')
        {            
            //Récupération de la Réservation - Modification
            if($this ->get('request') ->get('damias_resabundle_reservation')!==null)
            {
                $form_reservation->handleRequest($request);
                if ($form_reservation->isSubmitted() && $form_reservation-> isValid())
                {
                    $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                    $em->flush();
                    $date=$resa->getDateArrivee();
                    $session->set('date', $date);
                    $response = $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('damias_resa_homepage'));
                    return $response;
                }
            }
        }

        $response = $this->render(
            'DamiasResaBundle:Default:reservation_edit.html.twig',
            array(
                'form_reservation' => $form_reservation->createView(),
                'resa' => $resa
            )
        );
        return $response;
    }
```

My additional action that does not take into account validation:

```php
    public function ajouter_reservationAction()
    {
        // SESSION
        $session = $this->get('session');
        if ($session->get('resa')!=null) {
            $resa = new Reservation($session->get('resa'));
        }
        else {
            $resa = new Reservation();
        }
        $client = new Client();
        $request = $this->get('request');

        $form_client = $this        ->createForm(new ClientType,$client);
        $form_reservation = $this   ->createForm(new ReservationType, $resa);

        // Récupération des choix
        if($request->getMethod()=='GET')
        {
            // Récupération de la date de début
            if($this ->get('request') -> get('choix') !==null)
            {
                $choix=$this ->get('request') -> get('choix');
                $date_arrivee=$choix['date_encours']['date'];
                $date_arrivee = new \Datetime($date_arrivee);
                $date_depart = clone $date_arrivee;
                $date_depart->modify('+1 day');
                $ressourceId=$choix['ressource'];
                $em = $this ->getDoctrine()
                            ->getManager();
                $ressource = $em->getRepository('DamiasResaBundle:Ressource')->find($ressourceId);
                $id_categories=$choix['categories'];
                $resa   ->setDateArrivee($date_arrivee)
                        ->setDateDepart($date_depart)
                        ->addRessource($ressource);
                $session->set('resa', $resa);

                $categories = $ressource->getCategories();

                $form_reservation = $this   ->createForm(new ReservationType, $resa);
            }
        }
        // Récupération du formulaire
        if($request->getMethod()=='POST')
        {            
            // Récupération du nouveau client
            if($this ->get('request') ->get('damias_resabundle_client')!==null)
            {
                if ($form_client->handleRequest($request)-> isValid())
                {
                    $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                    $em->persist($client);
                    $em->flush();
                    $resa->setClient($client);
                    $session->set('resa', $resa);
                }
            }

            //Récupération de la Réservation
            if($this ->get('request') ->get('damias_resabundle_reservation')!==null)
            {
                $form_reservation->handleRequest($request);
                if ($form_reservation->isSubmitted() && $form_reservation-> isValid())
                {
                    $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                    $em->persist($resa);
                    $em->flush();
                    $date=$resa->getDateArrivee();
                    $session->set('date', $date);
                    $session->set('resa', null);
                    $response = $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('damias_resa_homepage'));
                    return $response;
                }
            }
        }

        $response = $this->render(
            'DamiasResaBundle:Default:reservation_new.html.twig',
            array(
                'form_reservation' => $form_reservation->createView(),
                'form_client' => $form_client->createView()
            )
        );
        return $response;
    }
```

Validation is done well when I modify an existing object, it does not work in the creation! Where is that from?
An idea? a track?

Thanks for your help
And sorry about the formatting my code, this is my first post and I have not found how to do (I'm not very comfortable with the language of Shakespeare)

Answer (score 0):

I found this old unresolved questions on the forum ...
My mistake was really stupid: in my validator, I had:

```
if (count ($ autre_resa)> 1
```

then I had to put:

```
if (count ($ autre_resa)> 0
```